# Common functionality for different types

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I have identified some common functionality in two of my datatypes, so like any programmer worth his salt I tried to factor it out:

```hs
module Binary where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Function
import Control.Monad


class Binary f where
  yes :: f a a
  no  :: f a b
  (..>) :: f a b -> f b c -> f a c

  yes' :: f a ()
  (~.>) :: f a b -> f a c -> f a c


try :: (Binary f, Alternative (f a)) => f a a -> f a a
try = (<|> yes)

try' :: (Binary f, Alternative (f a)) => f a () -> f a ()
try' = (<|> yes')

(.>) :: (Binary f, Alternative (f c)) => f a c -> f c c -> f a c
a .> b = a ..> try b

(~>) :: (Binary f, Alternative (f a)) => f a b -> f a () -> f a ()
a ~> b = a ~.> try' b

greedy :: (Binary f, Alternative (f a)) => f a a -> f a a
greedy = fix $ ap (.>)

greedy' :: (Binary f, Alternative (f a)) => f a () -> f a ()
greedy' = fix $ ap (~>)
```

As you can see, the types of `yes` and `yes'`, and `..>` and `~.>` are slightly different - they need to be for me to write instances - and so I end up with duplicate functions.

Is there a way I can get rid of `yes'` and `~.>`, and still make an instance of Binary with those types?

Here are my two instances:

```hs
module Example where

import Binary

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Category
import Data.List.Zipper as Z
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.State


newtype Opt a b = Opt { runOpt :: a -> Maybe b }

instance Category Opt where
  id = yes
  (Opt f) . (Opt g) = Opt $ g >=> f

instance Binary Opt where
  yes = Opt Just
  no = Opt $ const Nothing
  (..>) = (>>>)

---------

type Tape = Zipper
newtype Machine a b = Machine { unMachine :: MaybeT (State (Tape a)) b }

instance Functor (Machine a) where
  fmap f (Machine x) = Machine $ f <$> x

instance Applicative (Machine a) where
  pure = Machine . pure
  (Machine f) <*> (Machine x) = Machine $ f <*> x

instance Monad (Machine a) where
  (Machine a) >>= f = Machine $ a >>= unMachine <$> f

instance Binary Machine where
  no = Machine mzero
  yes' = pure ()
  a ~.> b = a >> b
```

Comment: "the types don't work out" is an incomplete write statement. Can you say more?

Comment: The types work out for me, after importing a couple modules.

Comment: Could you give an example instance or say more about the intent of this abstraction?

Comment: @luqui It is a little bit lengthy, but I have included a minimal version of my two instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a subtle inconsistency in your two instances -- that is, `Opt` and `Machine` do not quite have enough in common to share this much structure.  For example, the methods

```
yes :: f a a
(..>) :: f a b -> f b c -> f a c
```

are essentially a `Category`, as you have noticed (though I would simply make `Category` a superclass of `Binary` instead of duplicating those methods).  But `Machine` is not a category as it does not support composition.   Also, `Opt` is a profunctor (contravariant in its first argument, covariant in its second), whereas `Machine` is instead invariant on its first argument.  These are my hints that something needs to be changed before you try to abstract over these types.

My suspicion is that there is a missing parameter to `Machine`, and the state parameter is actually external to the `Binary` abstraction. Try using the [Kleisli category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) of your monad.

```
newtype Machine s a b = Machine { unMachine :: a -> MaybeT (State (Tape s)) b }
```

Now `Machine s` is a `Category` and the same sort of `Binary` that `Opt` is, and you don't need any of the primed combinators, and you can express any old `Machine a b`s as `Machine a () b` if you need to, but you can also probably generalize them.

In fact, the abstraction you are looking for may simply be [`ArrowZero`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowZero).  `Arrow` has a bit more structure than `Category`, so you should consider whether the rest of `Arrow` is applicable to your problem. If so, you have just opened a new toolbox of combinators, and you don't need to write any instances by hand because they are all covered by:

```
 type Opt = Kleisli Maybe
 type Machine s = Kleisli (MaybeT (State s))
```

(or in `newtype` style with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` if you prefer)